# Custom User Management for Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, session

I am using GAE Java for a multi-user application. There are multiple users with different roles. Each user can login, do some operations and logout. The business restricts me from using Google User Service and I need to implement my own for authentication and session management.

Can anyone please share with me how should I go about implementing my own user management? I have read its very tricky to implement own user management. Any pointers in terms of best approaches/ design / existing frameworks if any ?

I could see some similar posts but they are for python.

Comment: So far I have implemented this using usual java session management with Session object and maintaining an attribute in the session. I have tested this works on GAE, both in the development environment and on the cloud as well. GAE persists the session ids in the datastore and things work fine. I used Servlet Filter for ensuring authenticated access to all required urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the production quality authentication and security I finally decided using "Spring-Security". Seems to be the best solution if you are using spring in your application and you can do customizations at finest levels.