# custom authentication and authorization on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, authorization

im trying to understand how to implement my own authentication and authorization machinery for my GAE app. does anyone already implemented something like that and maybe can give me some advice?

what i need is grant access on certain sections to specific users and restrict the access to others.

i looked at repoze.who and reapoze.what but its not really clear to me how to use them on app engine.

thank you

Comment: at the end I choose a pretty simple solution by setting roles a User can have into a StringListProperty on my custom user object and checking the user permissions based on the role(s) it has with a decorator on the request. 
@Em: thank you i'll give it a quick look
@Gopi: im using python

Answer (score 1):

Maybe taking a look at **tipfy.ext.auth** ([doc](http://www.tipfy.org/docs/api/tipfy.ext.auth.html), [wiki](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/), [source code](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/),) and **tipfy.ext.acl** ([doc](http://www.tipfy.org/docs/api/tipfy.ext.acl.html), [wiki](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/acl/), [source code](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-acl/source/browse/)) would provide you with a little kickstart. Those are extensions built on top of [**tipfy**](http://www.tipfy.org/), a open source lightweight python-based framework made for GAE.

In order to get a better understanding of their usage and implementation, make sure to peek at the source code of each and the associated testsuites.

Comment: Note that next version of tipfy (v0.7) will include auth handling as part of the core of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear if you are using java or python. I have done my custom user management with authentication/authorization using [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) in java GAE. Things work fine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395033/custom-user-management-for-google-app-engine-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533144/user-api-for-google-app-engine-far-too-restrictive/3536139#3536139) are some more info/links from me.